# Question about using XML as an application-level protocol

Tags: networking, network-programming, protocols

I am wondering if I could use XML as the application-level protocol. The XML will just sit on-top of the TCP protocol and the 2 applications will just need to know how to parse XML.

But the problem is, XML is not compact enough. Should I use some algorithm to compact the XML payload before send it with TCP? If I do compact it, then the compressing/decompressing cost will be involved on both ends. What a dilemma. Any good suggestions? Or I take the wrong approach?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define "compact enough", have you measured it to be too slow for your application? Avoid [premature optimisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimization).

As with any protocol, there are trade-offs in various directions. XML buys you a well-known cross-platform format with libraries for just about any language, that's capable of representing all kinds of structured data. XMPP opts for this, and uses optional compression for bandwidth-constrained setups. Experiments in the XMPP world with alternate representations have rarely proven worth the effort.

A notch down from XML, but still providing many of the advantages is JSON. While it lacks namespacing it's fairly simple, and libraries are near as common as XML ones. Still, JSON is text-based and may still be verbose for some situations.

The last sensible choice would be a binary protocol. This has advantages in that you can tailor and optimise it specifically to your application. The disadvantages are that you have to write the parsing and serialization yourself, although there are tools to automate this such as Google's [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) project.

Ultimately all of these are suitable in different places, and the choice is up to the application developer for which one they should use for a given project.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that you can use straight XML for your messages and don't bother with compression or anything (XML isn't exactly blazingly fast) if you need a simple way of specifying how your messages look. If you need something faster and more compact, take a look at [Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/) or [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) (I personally prefer Protocol buffers, but everyone is not like me..).

Using XML can for instance be a good way if you need to make your interface be easy to interoperate with lots of different clients for instance (such as Web Services). If on the other hand you are always in charge of both ends of the communication, you can always do something quick to get going and then optimize later.